# SEO нового сайта

Tags: поиск, seo, поисковые-системы

Прошу советов по начальным работам `SEO` с новым сайтом. Не уверен какая информация необходима, поэтому: сайт сделан на `WordPress` и имеет информационный характер, оптимизация будет делаться на СНГ(по регионам не нужна), сайт пока на `http`, доступ поисковикам запрещен(от `WP`) и запросы в них не отсылались(на публикацию), сайт в процессе заполнения контентом. Ранее не доводилось заниматься оптимизацией, но слышал, что для Яндекса лучше как можно раньше открывать сайт(в процессе наполнения), для Гугл , вроде, наоборот. В общем, понимаю, что для всего есть специалисты, но хотелось бы самому(интересная тема). Прошу направления, может литературы, статьи и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам список терминов, гугл дальше поможет

- Микроразметка хлебных крошек
- Микроразметка контактов организаций (ну мало ли)
- Микроразметка в целом (для вас скорее всего не подойдет, но все равно почитайте)
- Meta-теги + Шаблонные описания и заголовки
- Meta-теги социальных сетей (twitter, google, facebook)
- Каноникалы \ Каноникальные ссылки \ canonical
- Яндекс.Метрика + Цели + Составные цели
- Google Analytics + Цели + Составные цели
- Sitemap (обновляемый, полноценный)
- Yml-feed (это больше для интернет-магазинов и к Яндекс маркету)

Если еще что-нибудь вспомню - дополню, но уже этих терминов Вам хватит, как новичку, на несколько вечеров

Comment: А конкретно про то, что лучше сайт на этапе наполнения или после(когда готов) открывать для поисковиков не знаете как поступить?

Comment: @ВладЮдкин точно говорить не берусь, но примерно за 1-2 недели до запуска сайта уже стоит открывать индексацию.

Answer (score 1):

- Если информация вашего веб-сайта имеет какое-то коммерческое
  содержание и/или связана с персональной/конфиденциальной информацией
  пользователей, то примените **[сертификат SSL](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html)**. Это является
  **[сигналом Гугл для поискового ранжирования](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html)**.
- Проверьте безопасность вашего веб-сайта с **[Sucuri](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/)** и **[URL Scanner](http://www.urlquery.net/)**.
- Правильно применяйте мета теги - **[инфо Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=ru)**, **[Ценность метаинформации для SEO (и как ее использовать)](https://www.stonetemple.com/metadata-seo-value)**.
- В 2018 году ожидается появление нового индекса Гугл "Мобильные первые". Это значит, что ранжирование результатов поиска для вашего стационарного компьютера будет основано на сигналах мобильной версии. Скорость загрузки веб-страниц важна для мобильного трафика. Мобильные пользователи ожидают загрузки веб-страниц от 2 до 3 секунд. Скорость загрузки уже является **[сигналом Гугл для поискового ранжирования для обычных компьютеров](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html)**, а с **[июля 2018 года это будет сигнал и для мобильного веба](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html)**.
- Соответственно и **[удобство для просмотра на мобильных устройствах является сигналом для поискового ранга Гугл](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6196932?hl=ru)**.
- Создавайте четкую и понятную структуру ваших веб-страниц с контуром ваших веб-страниц - **[инфо об этом](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/)**, **[валидатор контура](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/)**. Применяйте **[семантические элементы HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)** в исходном коде вашего веб-сайта. Дополнительно **[Оптимизация тегов заголовков](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/title-tag-seo/227429/)**. **[Инфо W3 о H1](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/h1only)**.
- Не допускайте ошибок исходного кода и исправляйте их - **[валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)**. 
  Браузеры при открытии веб-страниц создают **[объективные модели документов DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/constructing-the-object-model)**, что занимает какое-то время. Если в исходном коде имеются ошибки, это замедляет создание DOM, что влияет на скорость загрузки, что является сигналом поискового ранга (см. выше).
- Правильно применяйте **[структурированные данные](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)**. Эти данные должны отражать главное содержание каждой отдельной веб-страницы. Данные стартовой веб-страницы должны отражать ключевую информацию о всем вашем веб-сайте и/или о вашем бизнесе, представленном на веб-сайте. Дополнительно **[инфо Гугл о богатых результатах](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rich-results-tester.html)**, **[10 фактов о богатых результатах](https://searchengineland.com/10-facts-rich-results-seos-know-289078)**, **[спам в структур. данных](https://cognitiveseo.com/blog/16148/structured-markup-penalty/)**.
- Создавайте уникальное содержание - **[Советы по высококачественному контенту](https://searchengineland.com/high-quality-content-tips-googles-style-guide-282540)**, **[КОПИРАЙТИНГ И КОНТЕНТ](https://3qdigital.com/blog/2018-seo-part-5-copywriting-content)**.

Дополнительно **[Руководство по поисковой оптимизации для начинающих](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184)**, **[Что такое обновление основного ядра и как диагностировать изменения рейтинга?](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/diagnose-algo-update/232511/)**. Поисковая оптимизация - это непрерывный процесс. Если вы желаете иметь высокий органический трафик на ваш веб-сайт, то вам надо постоянно заниматься поисковой оптимизацией и онлайн менеджментом.